# control FAN speed

Tags: c#, windows-7-x64, acpi

I wanna control fan speed by C#. I tried WMI but it does not work for me :/ I have HP ProBook with Intel Core i5, Windows 7 HomePremium 64-bit. Is there any other way how to control fan speed (get temperature, set fan speed to higher or lower value or disable/enable it)?

Comment: Find out what API's programs like Speedfan use, and implement them in your program. There's not much more that can be said here.

Comment: Look at this [MSDN Forum Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/34f0fa55-567b-4a98-a29d-b92a5c9b5f8f/)

Comment: Judging from what I've seen trying to do similar stuff with SNMP, a lot of motherboards report the data, but in some proprietary fashion. It might be worth a shot checking the board maker's site (presumably HP here) for an SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Im trying to accomplish the same for a Dell Optiplex 740. Speed Fan also doesnt work for me. The funny part is that when i looked for a way to overclock my Graphic Card i found out under evga.com a way to change my CPU fan Speed. 
This is a (awsome) bug... As it is suposed to control my GPU fan and not CPU... But hey... Solved my issue where no other app does it.
Go there and give it a try. Maybe you can also get a quick solution.

Answer (score -1):

there are many applications that do that:

[speed fan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php)

Comment: I also tried this app, but it does not work for me. Probably it does not support my mb. So thats reason of my "other way" ask.

Comment: @sczdavos speedfan supports a buckload of chipsets and sensors, through years of experience gained while building the program. If it doesn't return fan speeds or temperatures on your PC, you're most likely not going to find them yourself anywhere.