# Set Fan Speed in C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I know this has been asked before, 
but I just can't seem to get it working.
I have called the following:

```
using System.Management;
using System.Management.Instrumentation;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

And I have tried this (I know it's pathetic, but its the best I found):

```
  [DllImport("Cimwin32.dll")]
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            uint32 SetSpeed( //???
              [in]  uint64 300
            );
        }
```

How can I set the computer's fan speed via c#?

Comment: Which fan do you want to set? Most computers have lots of them. And why do you want to do this? Wouldn't it be much easier to use a utility like SpeedFan?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, good points, And I didn't know that SpeedFan Utility even existed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# control FAN speed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391181/c-sharp-control-fan-speed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't your PInvoke be something like that:

```
[DllImport("Cimwin32.dll")]
static extern uint32 SetSpeed(in uint64 sp);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
           SetSpeed(300);
}
```

Also here's a C++ method to do so. You could put that in a DLL and call it from your C# code

[How can I control my PC's fan speed using C++ in Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786984/how-can-i-control-my-pcs-fan-speed-using-c-in-vista)

Comment: That is a valid pinvoke declaration. But that function doesn't exist so far as I can tell. Am I wrong?

Comment: I get an error in the unit64 section, it says that it can't find a definition for it.