# How to turn on/off chassis fan programmatically?

Tags: c#

I need to be able to turn off/on case fans to set cpu temperature in a desired range. Is it possible to do that specially?

Comment: I really hope some virus won't turn my fan off permanently.

Comment: Call the `StopAndCatchFire()` function.

Answer (score 1):

There is a open source project called [lm-sensors](http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/man/fancontrol).

> fancontrol is a shell script for use with lm_sensors. It reads its
>   configuration from a file, then calculates fan speeds from
>   temperatures and sets the corresponding PWM outputs to the computed
>   values.

Also check out;

- [Set Fan Speed in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655263/set-fan-speed-in-c-sharp)

You should learn about Windows system management interface also.

- [SetSpeed method of the CIM_Fan class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Calling a Provider Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390421%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Note: This only works if the motherboards supports this feature.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih Yes, or course. Beucase there is no direct way to control it IMO.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that, before people start complaining about it. ;)

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih Good thought ;)